# Shortcut to call recent inputs

Tags: notebooks, customization, keyboard

I am familiar with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to call the last input; however, in the case that I want to, for ease-of-comparison, want to print outputs of a command from further in the past and don't remember which output it was and deleted the notebook on which is was created, how can I do so? Is it not possible?

Comment: Have you seen `InString[]` and `Out[]`?

Comment: Yes, but I'm wondering if there is something similar to the up-arrow command for matlab's command window or the ENTRY button on a TI-83.